# Weird output on a simple C program

Tags: c

I have the following come in C:

```
int x = 0;
int *a = &x;

void foo(int *a)
{
    static int x = 0;
    x++;
    *a += x;
    a = &x;
    *a = x + 10;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    foo(a);
    foo(a);
    printf("%d\n", *a);

    return 0;
}
```

I can clearly debug it and see that the line `*a += x` doesn't do anything plus I can see that the value of x just a second before going out of the function is `22` and it prints out `13`.

When I did it in my head, I've go 34, which should be the right answer as far as I can see.
Can somebody explain where I might be wrong?

Comment: You have a global variable `x` and then one local in your `foo` function.  They conflict.  Change the name of one of them.

Comment: I know that the conflict, I want to know the output of this specific program. That was an interview question.

Comment: this works exactly as it should be.

Comment: and where is the problem? You are modifing the value of `a` that is on the stack... if you want to modify the global pointer a you should have `**a` as a function parameter...

Comment: I don't doubt a compiler at what it does. I have the simple question of why he does that.

Comment: Just remember that 'a' changes from pointing to the global 'x' to pointing to the static 'x' on the first call to the fucnction :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's do it step by step.

First round:

```
int x = 0; // global "x"

static int x = 0; // local "x" = 0
x++; // local "x" = 1
*a += x; // global "x" += local "x" results in global "x" = 1
a = &x; // local "a" points to local "x"
*a = x + 10; // local "x" = local "x" + 10 results in local "x" = 11
```

Second round:

```
int x = 0; // global "x" = 1 now

static int x = 0; // local "x" = 11 now
x++; // local "x" = 12
*a += x; // global "x" += local "x" results in global "x" = 13
a = &x; // local "a" points to local "x"
*a = x + 10; // local "x" = local "x" + 10 results in local "x" = 22

printf("%d\n", *a); // prints global "x", 13
```

Comment: Spot on!! Thanks for the great answer, now I understand!

Comment: a great and patient solution. although a static variable is local only in the sense of name lookup. Technically it is closer to a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy. The tricky part is to recognize the different copies of `x`, and the scope of `a` inside the function.

```
void foo(int *a)
{
    static int x = 0;
    x++;
    *a += x;
     a = &x;   //<==== this doesn't change the a outside you see, a now points to static x
    *a = x + 10;
 }
```

Single stepping it in a `gdb` should tell you what actually happens.
Just notice that on the line marked above, the `static int x` is changed. so the `*a=x+10;` actually changes the `static int x`. So after the first iteration:

Global `x`=1  static `x`=11

So in the second iteration
static `x` is incremented to `12`, then global `x=1+12;`. this makes global `x==13`. The rest of the code doesn't affect global `x` and global `a` anymore. The `foo` then simply adds the static `x` by 10, which is irrelevant to the global variable.

Comment: If it is 11, why does it print 13? Also, when debugging I saw that the global x changes a lot! It was 22 last time I checked.

Comment: @Vadiklk **after the first iteration**, global x is 1 and static x is 11. If you understand that, the second execution of `foo` is similar and you can understand the result.

Answer (score 0):

This makes it easier to see

```
int x = 0;
int *a = &x;

void foo(int *a)
{
    static int y = 0;
    y++;
    *a += y;

      a = &y;        // a doesn't point to x anymore!!!
    *a = y + 10;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    foo(a);
    foo(a); // Now 'a' again points to the global 'x' (once more) 
    printf("%d\n", *a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 because of local a... local a doesn't point to X anymore... global a still points to x.

Comment: here: foo(int *a) -> /*this `a` is local*/

Comment: @neagoegab Are you basically saying that the comment is in the wrong place?

Comment: @M.Alem You could also rename the parameter `a` to `b` for more clarity.

Comment: No the comment is in the right place. The thing is on second call to foo() a will still be poining to the global 'x' at entry until it reaches the commnet.

Comment: @M.Alem `*a += y;` doesn't change the pointer `a`, so the comment cannot refer to this line, it should refer to `a = &y;`.

Comment: Ya that's obvious. It is just a typo. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @M.Alem, i don't think it was only a typo... the comment is saying that `a` is not pointing to x anymore... probably thinking that global a has changed... you have missed the local a...

Answer (score 0):

Since C uses static scope, when there are two variables with the same name, it will be used first the one declared in the current block, then it will look at external blocks. So static int x shadows the global variable x. Also another thing that you should note is that in C arguments are passed by value, so if you assign a copy of the value you don't affect the original value.

Let's imagine a case where the global variable x has address 0x8000 , and the static variable x is at address 0x9000. This is what happens at the first call:

```
void foo(int *a)  // a= 0x8000 , global int x=0
{
    static int x = 0;
    x++;         // static int x=1
    *a += x;     // global int x=1
    a = &x;      // a=0x9000 (only a copy of a is assigned, so the global a will remain 0x8000)
    *a = x + 10;     // static int x= 11
}
```

And this is what happens in the second call:

```
void foo(int *a)  // a= 0x8000 , global int x=1, static int x=11
{
    static int x = 0;
    x++;         // static int x=12
    *a += x;     // global int x= 13
    a = &x;      // a=0x9000
    *a = x + 10;     // static int x= 22
}
```